Why is the router basename not getting configured?
This is the application code
`
<BrowserRouter basename="/app">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing/>} /> {/*  Renders at /app/ */}
        <Route path="/game" element={<Game/>}/>
      </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>

The output on the console when I run the service
`react-router-dom.js?v=24395915:213 <Router basename="/app"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything.`

The local server URL being generated doesn't include "/app" and is still defaulted to port 5173-i.e
http://localhost:5173/

Is it the job of the router to manage the app is deployed to /app? Try removing basename, it should work. manage the deployed pattern elsewhere...

Did you try visiting /app route manually?
When you give the base name the parameter to BrowserRouter, Vite will not automatically open the port at localhost:5173/app.
You need to manually visit the /app or /app/game path.
